# New Kernel just reloads boot menu over and over (including recovery mode) - Old Version loads fine

Tags: 20.04, package-management, kernel, updates

I have never quite run into anything like this before.  I am running the command line Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS and today I used apt update/upgrade to install some updates to packages.  Included was a Kernel update from Linux version 5.4.0-147-generic to version 5.4.0-152.   When it tries to boot either the normal or recovery versions of 152 it just comes back to the boot menu, then after the third time you try it shuts down the machine.  The older -147 version boots fine in both normal and recovery mode.

I have purged/removed all packages, regenerated the Kernel, checked disk space (and for errors) and the issue persists.   The most frustrating part is I don't see a single error message anywhere to give me a clue what to look at.  It just says "loading ram disk" and goes back to the menu.

I tried using the command line grub to load the image, thinking that at least I would get to see the error message, but nothing, just back to the menu when I told it to reboot.

I should mention that this is a virtual server hosted on a Hyper V host.   I don't think that would cause this issue, but again I don't have any clue what is failing, or where to look for where it is having a problem.  Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Again, -147 runs perfectly and has no errors of any kind in the logs.

Thanks